# Put condition on multiple columns to create a new column

Tags: excel

I have an excel file like

```
Acol   Bcol   Ccol  Dcol
 1       0     0     0
 0       1     1     0
 0       1     0     0
 0       0     1     0
 0       0     0     1
 1       1     1     0
```

I have to create a new flag column such that it takes value say 1 if only Acol is 1, 2 if only Bcol is 1, 3 if only Ccol is 1, 4 if only Dcol is 1 and 5 if multiple columns are 1, as below

```
Acol   Bcol   Ccol  Dcol   flag
 1       0     0     0      1
 0       1     1     0      5
 0       1     0     0      2  
 0       0     1     0      3
 0       0     0     1      4
 1       1     1     0      5
```

How do I do this in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the range of data in your example is A2:D2, then use in E2

```
=IF(SUM(A2:D2)>1,5,MATCH(1,A2:D2,0))
```

Copy and paste down.